# Which event to use for drop down menu - submenu closing on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

So I have a navigation with many sub drop down menus.

At the moment I am using hover event to open sub menus (hovered on parent a or the arrow icon).

The problem: Every time I try to hover over sub menu and sub menu's sub menu it closes.

***In the fiddle below: Try to hover Slowly to the sub menus (they close)***

It's annoying. Am I using the wrong event or the toggle approach is wrong?

```js
 /* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */

// Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first" ).toggleClass("toggle-on");
});


/* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
// Sub menu drop down 
 $(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
 });

$(".primary-toggle").click(function() {
  $(" .main-navigation ul:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

// $(".main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
//   $(".sub-menu").removeClass("toggle-on");
// });
```

```css
  /* 
  # HEADER
  */
  *, html {
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 22px;
  }
  .site-header {
   background-color: black;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
     padding: 1rem;
  }

 /* Burger Nav Styling */
 #sidebar-btn {
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:10px;
   position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  
 }
 #sidebar-btn span {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
 }
 #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
 }
 #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
 }


  /* Main Menu */
  .main-navigation {
  }


 /*.main-navigation .menu {
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;

  } */

 .menu-test-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

 }
 .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
 }

  .main-navigation ul {
    display: none;
  /*padding: 0 1rem;*/
   position: relative;
   background-color: yellow;

   }

  .main-navigation ul li {
   min-width: 140px;
   margin-right: 20px
  }
    .main-navigation ul li a {
     color: #fff;
     padding: 10px;
     text-decoration: none;
    }

  

 /* SUB Menu styles */
  .sub-menu.toggle-on {
   display: block; 
  }

  .main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
   list-style: none;
   display: none;
      margin-left:0;
     padding-left:0;
  }

 /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
   .main-navigation ul ul {
    
    background-color: pink;
    }

   .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    }

    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: green;
     top: 20px;
     left: 0;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: black;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }
     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: silver;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }

 @media  only screen and (min-width: 468px) {
 .site-header {
  flex-direction: column;
 }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
   display: none;
  }

  .primary-toggle {
   display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
   display: flex;
   background-color: blue;
  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background-color: blue;

  }

  .menu-test-container {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
  } /* end of */

  .main-navigation ul ul {
   position: absolute;
       /*left: 7.3rem;*/
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul {
   left: 7.3rem;
  }
  
 }

  /* TABLET MENU */  
 @media  only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-header {
  flex-direction: row;
 }
  body {
   background-color: yellow;
  }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
   display: none;
  }

  .primary-toggle {
   display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
   display: flex;
   background-color: blue;
  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background-color: blue;

  }
  .menu-test-container {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
  } /* end of */
   
   /* Sub menu navigation tablet */
   /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
    .main-navigation ul ul {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: pink;
      }


      .main-navigation ul ul li {
       padding: 7px 1px;
      }

      .main-navigation ul ul li a {
       font-size: 90%;
           padding: 10px 10px;

      }

    .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
     left: 7.3rem;
     top: 1px;
     background-color: blue;
     }

     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
      background-color: green;
      top: 20px;
      left: 0;
     }
     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
      background-color: black;  
      top:0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
      .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
      background-color: silver;  
      top:0px;
      left: 200px;
    }

 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c083bcc66d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">

  <div class="site-branding">
   <div class="site-branding-text">
    <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">LOGO</a></p>
   </div>
  </div><!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
   <button class="primary-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="sidebar-btn">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>    
    </div>   
   </button>
   <div class="menu-test-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">
     <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035">
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a>
      <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2076">
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a>
        <span class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

        </span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2082">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a>
          <span class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

          </span>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2081">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
             <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2079">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a>
              <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              </span>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
               <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
              </ul>
             </li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084">
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a>
     </li>
     <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2045">
      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
      <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </span>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2078">
        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a>
        <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>  
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are several issues here, you need to add and on and off hover handlers, also, you need to use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop propagating the hover event to parent elements. Overall, I would advise against this type of menu as it is a bad user experience: http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/

Comment: new to javascript, can you please give me an example of a "good practise" menu please?

Comment: here is a really helpful article that describes good navigation: http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/the-rules-for-modern-navigation/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set a [`.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) on mouseleave and clear that timeout on mouseenter. So if the mouseenter occurs in less time that the delay setted, the things to do on mouseleave won't be done.

[`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) allows to define two different handlers, use them!

```js
var menu_timeout;

$("#site-navigation li").hover(
  function(){  // Mouseenter
    var that = $(this);
    that.find(".sub-menu:first").addClass("toggle-on");
    clearTimeout(menu_timeout);
  },
  function(){  // Mouseleave
    var that = $(this);
    menu_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      that.find(".sub-menu:first").removeClass("toggle-on");
    },250);
  }
);
```

```css
/* 
# HEADER
*/
*, html {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.site-header {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* Burger Nav Styling */
#sidebar-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;

}
#sidebar-btn span {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
}
#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Main Menu */
.main-navigation {
}


/*.main-navigation .menu {
display: none;
padding: 1rem;

}  */

.menu-test-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

}
.main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  display: none;
  /*padding: 0 1rem;*/
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;

}

.main-navigation ul li {
  min-width: 140px;
  margin-right: 20px
}
.main-navigation ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}



/* SUB Menu styles */
.sub-menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;  
}

.main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin-left:0;
  padding-left:0;
}

/* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
.main-navigation ul ul {

  background-color: pink;
}

.main-navigation ul  ul ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: green;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: black;    
  top:0px;
  left: 200px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: silver;    
  top:0px;
  left: 200px;
}

@media  only screen and (min-width: 468px) {
  .site-header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
    display: none;
  }

  .primary-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
    display: flex;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: blue;

  }

  .menu-test-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }  /* end of */

  .main-navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    /*left: 7.3rem;*/
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 7.3rem;
  }

}

/* TABLET MENU */  
@media  only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .site-header {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
    display: none;
  }

  .primary-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
    display: flex;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: blue;

  }
  .menu-test-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }  /* end of */

  /* Sub menu navigation tablet */
  /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
  .main-navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
  }


  .main-navigation ul ul li {
    padding: 7px 1px;
  }

  .main-navigation ul ul li a {
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 10px 10px;

  }

  .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
    left: 7.3rem;
    top: 1px;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
    background-color: green;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
    background-color: black;    
    top:0px;
    left: 200px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
    background-color: silver;    
    top:0px;
    left: 200px;
  }

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c083bcc66d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">

    <div class="site-branding">
      <div class="site-branding-text">
        <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">LOGO</a></p>
      </div>
    </div><!-- .site-branding -->

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
      <button class="primary-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
        <div id="sidebar-btn">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>        
        </div>   
      </button>
      <div class="menu-test-container">
        <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">
          <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2076">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a>
                <span class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
                  <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

                </span>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2082">
                    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a>
                    <span class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
                      <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>

                    </span>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                      <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2081">
                        <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a>
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                          <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                          <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2079">
                            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a>
                            <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                              <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </span>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                              <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"> asdasd</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2045">
            <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
            <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2078">
                <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a>
                <span class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="dropdown-symbol"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                </span>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
                    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>    
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```